# Elegant way to set the DateTime to the latest business hour

Tags: c#, date, date-math

I want to set an "As Of" value on a record reflecting the latest business hour available.

For example, let's say we define business hours as M-F, 9AM to 5PM.  If I invoke this on a Thursday at 4:00PM, the "As Of" should be Thursday at 4:00PM; however, if I invoke this at 1:30AM Monday morning, the "As Of" should be 5:00PM on the previous Friday.

I can bull through this with a bunch of logic, but it just seems like this would be a "feature" of some class where the work is pretty much already done, or there is a simple way to do it.

Is there?  Or am I stuck writing some odious algorithm?

Comment: I guess you're stuck and need to write your own logic... :)

Comment: What are you talking about? You need a method written in c# for this? If so what have you tried?

Comment: I'm hoping I don't need a method written in C# for this; I'm hoping there is a class or mechanism already pre-existing for it.

Comment: Nope, nothing exist out of the box.

Comment: There is no such class in the .net framework since its pretty specific. You will have to create your own class with datetimes and timespans.

Comment: Sigh... that's what I was afraid of.  .NET has surprised me on occasion with nifty little features, so I was hoping.  Oh well.

Comment: Well, google may help too. There are lots of business applications with your specific problem. Good luck. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not include anything for this out of the box, but you could try something like this:

```
public DateTime? GetLatestOpen(DateTime current) 
{
    var openHours = ...collection of pairs of  int (Day) and two date times (TimeRange[])...
    if (!openHours.Any()) { return null; } //prevent inf. loop if no open hours ever

    var currentDay = current.DayOfWeek;
    var hoursToday = openHours.FirstOrDefault(oh => oh.DayOfWeek == currentDay);

    if (hoursToday != null)
    {
        var currentTime = current.TimeOfDay();
        if (currentTime >= hoursToday.TimeRange[0] && 
            currentTime <= hoursToday.TimeRange[1]) 
        {
            return currentTime;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return hoursToday.TimeRange[1];
        } 
    }

    return GetLatestOpen(current.AddDays(-1));
}


...

var latestOpen = GetLatestOpen(DateTime.Now);

...
```

Your `openHours` collection would look something like the following (I used an anonymous type for simplicity of the example):

```
var openHours = new [] { new { Day = 1, TimeRange = new DateTime[] { ...Open..., ...Close...} }, new { Day = 2...... } };
```

**Notes:**

A couple things to note about the above:

1. `Day = 0` is Sunday, `Day = 1` is Monday .... `Day = 6` is Saturday
2. You can use another type of collection for the `TimeRange`, if you want
3. For the `...Open...` and `...Close...` `DateTime` objects, you need not worry about the actual Date; you only carry about the Time portion

Let me know if you have any questions on this. I hope this helps! Good luck, and happy coding! :)

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **CalendarPeriodCollector** of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public DateTime GetLatestBusinessHour( DateTime moment )
{
  // filter the business hours: - Monday to Friday, 9AM to 5PM
  CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter filter = new CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter();
  filter.AddWorkingWeekDays();
  filter.CollectingHours.Add( new HourRange( 9, 17 ) );

  // collect business hours of the past week
  CalendarPeriodCollector collector = new CalendarPeriodCollector( filter,
    new TimeRange( moment.AddDays( -7 ), moment ), SeekDirection.Forward,
    new TimeCalendar( new TimeCalendarConfig { EndOffset = TimeSpan.Zero } ) );
  collector.CollectHours();

  // end of the last period
  return collector.Periods.End;
} // GetLatestBusinessHour
```